# Power BI - Rolling average

Tags: powerbi

I tried to refer to the forums and other questions on stack overflow, but couldn't find the one similar to mine.

I have used the following DAX to calculate the 30 DAY moving average (I just re-modified the original Time-intelligence Rolling average calculation from Quick measure).

```
30DayQuickMeasureRollingAvg = 
    VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('DateTable'[Date].[Date])
    RETURN
        AVERAGEX(
            DATESBETWEEN(
                'DateTable'[Date].[Date],
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -30, DAY),
                __LAST_DATE
            ),
            CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('UserTable'[userID]))
        )
```

When I use this, my moving average graph displays the future 30 day aswell like below

[image]

So how do I exclude the future time?

I have even tried this @JTBR2 solution from here [Power BI Rolling Average](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054452/power-bi-rolling-average)

But it didn't work either.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing your date table has future dates in it. You should be able to add a condition to not display dates past today like this:

```
30DayQuickMeasureRollingAvg = 
    VAR __LAST_DATE = LASTDATE('DateTable'[Date].[Date])
    VAR RollingAverage = 
        AVERAGEX(
            DATESBETWEEN(
                'DateTable'[Date].[Date],
                DATEADD(__LAST_DATE, -30, DAY),
                __LAST_DATE
            ),
            CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT('UserTable'[userID]))
        )
    RETURN IF(__LAST_DATE > TODAY(), BLANK(), RollingAverage)
```

Comment: That was a pretty simple change. Thanks!

Comment: Oh no! I just realized that the graph (Rolling avg) is turning into straight line when I tend to click on any month (in the other graph). Why is this so? How to fix this?

Comment: Like for e.g. the moving avg is fine for all 4 months (as above picture) and if I click on any month (say Feb), the moving avg is displaying a complete straight line.

Comment: That sounds like a different question. Please post it separately.

Comment: thank you so much for the question and the great tip. I just tried this and it worked. Just one small thing to add, I still had one more day after the last day using the code above. But if I change it to __LAST_DATE >= TODAY(), then it worked perfectly. So hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Try using this formula:

```
Rolling12MonthsSum = 
  var Ldate = date(max('Year'[Year]) , max('Month'[Monthnumber]),1) 
  //Last date

  var Fdate = EDATE(Ldate,-11) //First date

  var pm_hrs = sum(Query1[pm_hrs])/sum(Query1[acthrs]) //Calculation

  return

  if(min('Date'[Date])<fdate,
       blank(),
     if(min('Date'[Date])>Ldate,
               blank(),
              pm_hrs))
```

Right now I am using it for 12 months rolling sum you can replace it with days and average. Just change the -11 to -1 it will give exact one month data output.

You will need to create a 'Date' Table or 'Calendar' table to achive this.
Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to understand everything but what exactly are Query1[pm_hrs] and Query1[acthrs]?

Comment: those are columns from my table 'Query1' which I used for calculation of the KPI. In the calculation area you can give your own varable names like I have given pm_hrs coz I was calculating % PM Hours for 12 months from the selected month.